# Overlapping of two buttons in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a content table using SAPUI5 but when I am trying to add more than one button they are getting overlapped.

Code:

```
var page2 = new sap.m.Page("page2",{
  title : "Contents",
  showNavButton : true,
  navButtonPress : function() {        
    app.back();//go back to previous page
  },
  content : new sap.m.Button({
    text : "Introduction",
    press : function() {          
      app.to("page3");//navigate to Home
    },
    //enabled : false
    type : sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent
  }),
  content : new sap.m.Button({
    text : "Iview",
    press : function() {          
      app.to("page3");//navigate to Home
    },
    //enabled : false
    type : sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent
  })
});
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you share both the screenshots of what you exactly want and  overlapping Buttons.

Comment: `content` is an aggregation, you can pass multiple objects to it into an array, but do not repeat the content assignment. @prashanth-rajasekaren gave you the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var Button1 = new sap.m.Button({
        text : "Introduction",
        press : function() {
          //navigate to Home
          app.to("page3");
        },
        //enabled : false
        type : sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent
      });


    var Button2 = new sap.m.Button({
        text : "Iview",
        press : function() {
          //navigate to Home
          app.to("page3");
        },
        //enabled : false
        type : sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent
      })



    var page2 = new sap.m.Page("page2",{
      title : "Contents",
      showNavButton : true,
      navButtonPress : function() {
        //go back to previous page
        app.back();
      },
      content : [Button1, Button2]


    });

page2.placeAt("body");
```

Comment: It would be great if you add some lines explaining @aditi-garg why your solution is correct and where she made a mistake. It will help her to not make the same mistake again in the future :)